# How to set two 'projects' build config in Nx workspace project.json similar to angular.json?

Tags: angular, typescript, nrwl-nx, nrwl, single-spa-angular

Here angular.json file has two project configs:

- one for single-spa, and another config for local dev build.
  See image and git link:

[image]

https://github.com/Abdelrahman-H-Mahmoud/single-spa-demo/blob/main/angular-app/angular.json#L133

Problem: After migration to Nx workspace (v16 and above). Nx only migrates the "angular-app-single" build config to "project.json"

**How to modify *project.json* in Nx worksapce to contain two build config setup similar to angular.json- that is**

```
"projects": {
      "angular-app-single": { /*build 1 code*/},
      "angular-app": { /*build 2 code*/}
}
```

**Note**: These are two different configurations in angular.json file for one project. 1.First config “angular-app-single” is using Webpack builder and main.single-spa.ts. 2.Second config is using angular devkit builder and main.ts.
The problem is after migration to Nx the project.json file has only one config.

I tried looking at https://nx.dev/ docs.

Comment: Each application can only have a single `project.json` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
I found the solution to my own question:

In Nx workspace `project.json` file I have added two build configs under *targets*.

Two `build` and `serve` configs: one for single-spa webpack and another for local.

```
"targets":{ /*see image */}
```

[image]

In each `serve` update `"browserTarget"` to respective `"build-name"`

In addition, open `package.json` file and update build and serve in `"scripts":{}`

Answer (score 0):

In NX workspace there are separated projects (https://nx.dev/nx-api/angular).

Therefore having two apps (angular-app-single, angular-app) two or three projects have to be considered:

1. angular-app
2. angular-app-single
3. shared (optional) - code that is shared the two above

Comment: These are two different configurations in angular.json file for one project. 1.First config “angular-app-single” is using Webpack builder and main.single-spa.ts. 2.Second config is using angular devkit builder and main.ts.

Comment: In NX workspace there is project.json for every project. Maybe you need need two target builds in one project.json file?

Comment: Thanks! Found ideas from this github link (question)-  https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/16133   .I tried adding two builds as shown in github link.